# SQL operations performance : column numbers, SUM

Tags: mysql

I am developing an app that has people answer questions, and it is already storing the number of correct and incorrect questions in different columns. For other functions (such as all time score) I need to get the total amount answered per day, for all time, etc.

So, it is better to:
1. With each question answer, store to the DB: answer_correct,answer_incorrect, and answers_total

OR

1. With each answer, store to the DB: answer_correct, answer_incorrect,
2. When doing the ranking functions, have the database SUM those at that time?

I know this seems very generic but as I get deeper into MySQL I am trying to develop best practices re: performance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questionId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isCorrect` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`questionId`),
  KEY `isCorrect` (`isCorrect`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

On each answer you add a record into this table. When you need, you get number of correct/incorrect answers during given period from this table.

..I don't know if users are allowed to answer one question several times, mind the primary index.

Comment: Wow, and I had thought to store one record per session, or even per day! You think the transactional price (sorry if right term) isn't bad to store one record per question?

Comment: The MyISAM engine i mentioned does not even support transactions, and it is going to be fast until you have tens of millions records in this table. If you use innodb which does support transactions, there will be no "transactional price" on insertion/deletion of records into this table until you link it with others somehow

Comment: It is InnoDB (i'm building onto a WP db) - do you still recommend your structure in terms of speed/size?

Comment: It is going to be the same while the queries you make are simple and use indexes. Be sure to use EXPLAIN to check

Comment: but if we have thousands of people playing hundreds of moves, we're getting into the high numbers - that won't affect SUMming of columns, etc?